# How to do parallax effect for particular layout and make toolbar fixed

Tags: android

My code is like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

         <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileCover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_cover_height"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_header_signup"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/sign_up_toolbar"
                style="@style/TransparentToolbar"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                android:alpha="1"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

           <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           .........
           </RelativeLayout>
```

**Problem here is my V7.Widget.toolbar remains fixed,Imageview does parallax effect, but  *app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary* is not working to change the color of v7.widget**